# NhiberNate Map by code does not contain a definision for 'id'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have played around with NHiberNate, I got it to work with xml definision, but I'm stuck in my Map by Code test. 
I have the following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;
using NHibernate.Mapping;


namespace NHibernatePets
{
public class Pet
{
    virtual public int id { get; set; }
    virtual public string PetName { get; set; }
    virtual public string Species { get; set; }
    virtual public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    virtual public string Speak()
    {
        return "Hi.  My name is '" + PetName + "' and I'm a " + Species    + " born on " + Birthday + ".";
    }
}

public class PetMap : ClassMapping<Pet>
{
    public PetMap()
    {
        table("Pet");

        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.Petname, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Species, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Birthday, map => map.NotNullable(true));
    }
```

When I hit f5 i gives me following error mesage

> Error 15  'NHibernatePets.Pet' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type     'NHibernatePets.Pet' could be found (are you missing a using     directive or an assembly reference?)
>       }

My plan was to be able to do a query on the PET database as this

```
using (ISession session = OpenSession())
{
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(" FROM Pet");
    IList<Pet> pets = query.List<Pet>();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("pets.Count = " + pets.Count);
    pets.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Speak()));
}
```

It worked when I used xml to map the table. 
What do i do wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is case sensitive and because the ID property is named "**`id`**"

```
public class Pet
{
    virtual public int id { get; set; }
```

We cannot map it as Id

```
Id(x => x.Id... // there is no Id on x === Pet
```

So, to follow common naming conventions in C# just change property name to **`Id`**

```
public class Pet
{
    //virtual public int id { get; set; }
    virtual public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir ;)